# How can I post photo to facebook with python sdk

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, multipartform-data

I am using the [python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/newsfeed) on google app engine, and I'm runnig the "newsfeed" example. I tried to change the example code in order to upload local image file to facebook.

And follow is my change, but i don't know how to finish it. I'm wondering that how to change facebookclient.py or facebook.py to upload image.

Thanks

***home.html***

```
<form action="/post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="textbox"><textarea name="message"></textarea></div>
    <div><input name="image" type="file"/></div>
    <div class="buttons"><input type="submit" value="Share"/></div>
</form>
```

***facebookclient.py***

```
class PostHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        message = self.request.get("message")
        image = self.request.get("image")
        if not self.current_user or not message:
            self.redirect("/")
            return
        try:
            # self.graph.put_wall_post(message)
        except:
            pass
        self.redirect("/")
```

Comment: It seems like file uploads are unsupported in the current Python SDK but there's what appears to be a good patch for this here: http://www.vibesphere.com/2011/07/file-uploads-hack-for-facebook-python-sdk/ (haven't tested it)

Answer (score 0):

Using the facebook API is a bit more complicated: a single request won't do the trick, there's authentication involved.

Fortunately, the documentation is quite good. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), and look under the Publishing section for your specific needs.

Comment: This response is very vague.  It doesn't cover anything related to the python API.  Assume that authentication is already handled.  I have the same question, but I'm trying to upload an image for an event.  I'm doing something similar to: graph.put_object("me", "events", name=post.title, start_time=start_time, end_time=start_time, picture=<data>), but I can't figure out what format to use for <data>.  The newly-created event keeps coming up with a blank image.